# How to remove multiple buttons that I created with a loop?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

**EXPLANATION:**

1) I initiate the button above the class :

```
var myButton = UIButton()
```

2) I then create x amount of buttons depending on how many items are in an array

```
for letter in arrayOfLetters {


            myButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: buttonX, y: 500, width: someFloat, height: someFloat))
            buttonX = buttonX + thirdFloat  //spacing


            myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5  
            myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
            myButton.setTitle("\(letter)", forState: UIControlState.Normal) 
            myButton.titleLabel?.text = "\(letter)"
            myButton.addTarget(self, action: "myButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

            self.view.addSubview(myButton)  



        }
```

3) Later on once the user has pressed the correct buttons, I call a function to refresh and I want to remove all buttons. This is so I can generate new buttons based on new array

```
myButton.removeFromSuperview()
```

**ISSUE:**

However this does nothing, I tried giving the buttons a tag and deleting buttons by tag == tagId but nothing happened.

I can delete all views but it deletes everything else,

I tried this but again nothing happends

```
var buttons = [myButton]
            for button in buttons as! [UIButton] {
                button.removeFromSuperview()
            }
```

I want to delete all buttons I added and i'm either not deleting them or deleting everything in the view

Comment: You can also remove buttons by assigning `tag` value to each button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EASY FIX:**

1) Inside Class, out of any func:

```
var buttonsArray = [UIButton]()
```

2) Declare `myButton` here and add the `append` line:

```
for letter in arrayOfLetters {


     var myButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: buttonX, y: 500, width:     someFloat, height: someFloat))
```

...

```
     self.buttonsArray.append(myButton)
}
```

3) To remove buttons:

```
for btn in buttonsArray {
    btn.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

**EXPLANATION:**

Always store in an array the elements you create with a loop if you want to easily remove all of them at once.

Answer (score 2):

you are re-assigning the myButton variable as you loop.

Remove this line:

```
var myButton = UIButton()
```

add a property at the top to hold the buttons:

```
var buttons:[UIButton]()
```

then later in your code:

```
for letter in arrayOfLetters {


        var myButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: buttonX, y: 500, width: someFloat, height: someFloat))
        buttonX = buttonX + thirdFloat  //spacing


        myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5  
        myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        myButton.setTitle("\(letter)", forState: UIControlState.Normal) 
        myButton.titleLabel?.text = "\(letter)"
        myButton.addTarget(self, action: "myButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(myButton)  

        self.buttons.append(myButton)

    }
```

Then you should be able to remove like so:

```
for button in self.buttons {
    button.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

This should resolve your issue, But it's important to understand what the problem was, so you define a new button as a property with this line: `var myButton = UIButton()`. This holds ONE button. as you are looping through creating buttons you are overriding the button with the next one.

So if anything, Calling myButton.removeFromSuperView() will remove the last one you created. Doing it the way I suggested means  you create a button and add it to an array of buttons, so later you can iterate over the array referencing each button in turn and remove it.

Comment: Whilst i accepted the solution above, your explanation on understanding the problem was helpful. Thanks for this

Comment: Your welcome, not sure who downvoted it, the accepted answer was added after and is just this without as much explanation

Answer (score 2):

i hope it will help for you give tag for your button while you are adding delete that button

```
     for button in self.view.subviews {
  if button.tag == 100 {
    button.removeFromSuperview()
}
}
```